# ClientFunction: _axios2 is not defined

Tags: automated-tests, axios, session-cookies, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm running TestCafe for UI automation, using ClientFunctions to trigger API requests (so that I can pass along session cookies).

Currently I have a ClientFunction with [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) which works fine... except we're now testing IE 11 and Fetch is unsupported.

Fetch code:

```js
const fetchRequestClientFunction = ClientFunction((details, endpoint, auth, method) => {
  return window
    .fetch(endpoint, {
      method,
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: new Headers({
        accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }),
      body: JSON.stringify(details),
    })
    .then(httpResponse => {
      if (httpResponse.ok) {
        return httpResponse.json();
      }
      return {
        err: true,
        errorMessage: `There was an error trying to send the data ${JSON.stringify(
          details
        )} to the API endpoint ${endpoint}. Status: ${httpResponse.status}; Status text: ${httpResponse.statusText}`,
      };
    });
});
```

However when I try to switch it to [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)... not so much:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const axiosRequest = ClientFunction((details, endpoint, auth, method) => {
  return axios({
      method,
      auth,
      url: endpoint,
      data: details,
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      timeout: 3000,
    })
    .then(httpResponse => {
      if (httpResponse.status < 300) return httpResponse;

      return {
        err: true,
        errorMessage: `There was an error trying to send the data ${JSON.stringify(
          details
        )} to the API endpoint ${endpoint}. Status: ${httpResponse.status}; Status text: ${httpResponse.statusText}`,
      };
    });
});
```

Tried using `window.axios`, and also passing `axios` as a dependency. I've also tried making the axios request without the ClientFunction... and despite getting response of 200, the website wasn't updated as expected.

Each time I either get `_axios2 is not defined` or `window.axios is not a function`. I would greatly appreciate some guidance here.

Comment: Have you considered the [Roles](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/authentication/user-roles.html) API or [RequestHooks](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/creating-a-custom-http-request-hook.html#the-onrequest-method) to work with cookies?

Comment: We actually had to stop using Roles, due to session leakage (causing tests to fail with a stale session state). Couldn't easily reproduce, so didn't raise a bug.  I'll look at RequestHooks, but our cookies are ServerSide (http only) and I won't be able to add them to the request (I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TestCafe [ClientFunctions](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/clientfunction/) allow only serializable objects as dependencies. You need to have `axios` on the client side to send such a request.

Comment: Trying to load `axios` to the client violates our CSP... trying to look in to alternative options just now